# bigquery non greedy REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

How to extract shortest match(lazy, non-greedy) for REGEXP_SUBSTR function?

Regex `.*?` should return non-greedy result.

But bigquery REGEXP_SUBSTR returns `{"r": [{"l": 10, "s": 1, "t": ["1"]}, {"l": 100, "s": 3, "t": ["3", "4"]}`
instead of `{"l": 100, "s": 3, "t": ["3", "4"]}` with regex = `r'\{.*?"t": \["3", "4"\]\}'`

Are there hints for this?

Note: JSONPATH is not work for me (i.e. jsonpath array filter is not supported by bigquery.)

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT r'{"r": [{"l": 10, "s": 1, "t": ["1"]}, {"l": 100, "s": 3, "t": ["3", "4"]}]}' AS jstr
)
SELECT 
   jstr
  ,REGEXP_EXTRACT(jstr, r'\{.*?"t": \["3", "4"\]\}') AS e1
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery does support JSON paths. I think this will work for you:

```
JSON_QUERY(jstr, '$.r[0].t')
```

As for your regexp, it's consistent with standard regexp behavior as far as I can tell.

I **think** the issue is that you're expecting the non-greedy operator to find the shortest possible match for this substring, but that's not really what it's intended to do. The non-greedy operator just says "consume as few repetitions as possible when looking for a match" -- and the regexp finds the first brace, consumes as few characters as possible until it hits '[3, 4]', and stops -- success!

If you were in greedy mode, it'd keep searching forward for another possible '[3, 4]' match. In non-greedy mode, it stops at the first one -- but doesn't backtrack to get the absolute smallest sequence possible.

Comment: JSON_QUERY with filter is not work on bigquery. I'd love to find `t` with ['3', '4'] but not `t` with ['1']

Maybe I should using JSON_QUERY_ARRAY with a cross join and filtering by where clause.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination for `non-greedy` search mode : )

Comment: Ah, understood about the filter. Your JSON_QUERY_ARRAY plan sounds reasonable.